# Excel Index Function

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I just want to thank you guys in advance. I think you guys are doing a great job in helping people out with programming stuff. Pats on the back for all of you.

Here is what I've been working on: I have daily stock price return data on about 4000 stocks. I want to add them to my portfolio after observing their performance for 12 months. I will choose the top 10% best performers and bottom 10% worst performers. I will create multiple portfolios over a period of time. I have done that with no problem.

I want to use the INDEX function to calculate the daily return of my portfolio. Not all 4000 stocks are in my portfolio, about 300 stocks are in my portfolio at any given time. The daily portfolio returns will be calculated by multiplying the weights (they are equal weighted, so 1/300) to that stock's return on the specific date. I assume it has to do with a combination of INDEX, SUMPRODUCT, and IF or MATCH functions.

I have been thinking this for a long time and I just can't get to the bottom of it. I have attached pictures for a portion of what I was working on. I think will give you a good picture of what I'm trying to do. I bet this is such an easy thing for you guys. I hope you can help me out! Thanks again!

PICTURES:[IN or OUT portfolio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKqym.png) & [Stock's individual returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3e10X.png)

Charles

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your problem, but here is a trial suggestion:

You get data for 4000 stocks while you are monitoring 300. So, you need to find the correct one within your sheet (there will be 3700 that will not match anything).

If you have your stocks listed in, say, column "A", you could use the function `LOOKUP` (well explained in the Web). If you need to get the row of your stock, you can use the function `MATCH`.

If this is not what you are looking for, it means that I (at least) did not understand you, so you would need to add details to your question.

Comment: Yes that is easy to do for one day. But I need to be able to do this for multiple days. I just thought there would be a better way than typing the same code with different cell references for about 165 times...

Comment: You could write a simple MACRO for that.

Comment: @CharlesLee, a MACRO is a piece of program that you can execute as many times as you wish. So, if you write a SUITABLE MACRO using the SUITABLE functions you will be able to run it on a daily basis. In order to provide mire detailed guidance, I need more details on how your EXCEL is built, how you get data, etc.

Comment: I am aware of the MACRO program. Thank you for letting me know that there is one that can help me, but I am unsure how I would construct it. I don't expect you to lay out a whole tutorial for me to do it, but any place I could go to create one like how I need it to function would be great.

Comment: The lookup doesnt also solve the multiplication that I have to do

Comment: I would have to do vlookup1(lookupvalue, ref, column) * weight + vlookup2(lookupvalue, ref, column) * weight + vlookup2(lookupvalue, ref, column) * weight + vlookup3(lookupvalue, ref, column) * weight...till vlookup196(lookupvalue, ref, column) * weight!

Comment: As stated, You can handle that with a MACRO. I suggest you take a look at MS docs. Plenty of examples there. Good luck.

Comment: Also I have multiple data points. I will have a few million lookups which is already lagging my spreadsheet. I feel like your answer is very overly simple and doesn't consider my questions from many angles.

Comment: Disagree. With a rather simple MACRO you could achieve very many things, regardless of how many data elements you need to handle (for instance, you can set a loop that goes through all cells in a column that have data and process them, without setting upfront the boundaries of the range). Still, this is the most I can say based on the information you posted. Again, good luck!!!